# Why cloudfront cdn is not faster in chrome-devtool, but faster using network tool like httping

Tags: networking, google-chrome-devtools, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I host static files by aws cloudfront cdn

It is result that get file from server, it took 4.62s.
My location in Taipei, and server in Tokyo.
[image]

And it is from cloudfront cdn, it took 4.97s.
[image]

I try a lot of times, the cdn response always slower than server.

But when I use some track tools like httping
cdn(avg: 159.3ms) is faster than server(313.3ms)

Can somebody tell me why?? 
I believe the cdn response is faster than server

Comment: 412KiB in 4+ seconds seems too slow, either way, doesn't it?  Is your connectivity limited?  Are you running httping on the same machine as the browser?  If you use `dig` to find the IP addresses of your CloudFront distribution (as seen from your location), and then `dig -x` to look up the names of those addresses, you should find a 4 or 5 character code in each of the hostnames, like nrt4 or iad52.  The letters shown are the IATA code of the airport nearest to the CloudFront edge that is currently handling requests originating from your workstation.

Comment: Any way to check if my connectivity limited or not?

Comment: I running httping on the same machine as the browser

Comment: When I asked "is your connectivity limited," that was a question about *your* Internet connection -- is it a narrow bandwidth or high latency connection?

Comment: ok, I understand what you said. So my Internet connection is not the root cause, because httping and browser on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  If you use `dig` or `nslookup` on the hostname that points to CloudFront, what are some of the IP addresses you get back in the response?